# lg 27md5klb webcam not found

Tags: webcam

Using cable that came with monitor to connect to macbook pro (2019) running 10.15.1. The built-in usb webcam is not found by the mac.

Do I need to also connect the usb from the monitor to the macbook pro? I hope not, because the mbp only has usb-c ports which means I need to buy an adapter.

Comment: You need to clarify precisely which "cable that came with monitor"

Comment: You state you're using the cable that came with the monitor to connect to the MBP.  Then you ask if you need to use the usb from the monitor to the MBP.  Can you clarify what you're doing, exactly, and what the problem is, exactly?  Also, have you checked with LG on how to connect their product to a MBP?

Comment: I'm using the black thunderbolt 3 cable. I checked with LG. It's a faulty monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted LG. Faulty monitor. Getting it serviced. If anyone is curious, they pay for shipping, but it takes 10 business days to fix. Will report back.